# Why is the top bar on Super User smaller than on other sites?

Tags: support, design, top-bar

According to [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/360858/4284627), the top bar's height has been changed to 50px on all Stack Exchange sites in order to have the same height on Stack Overflow and on other sites. However, on Super User, the top bar's height is still 40px. I've looked at Stack Overflow, Meta Stack Exchange and a few other random sites, and their top bars are all 50px high. According to what I've seen, it's only Super User that has a 40px high top bar.

Also, the search box is lighter on Super User than on other sites. On Meta Stack Exchange and other sites, the search box was made darker as a result of [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/302017/349538), but it hasn't changed on Super User.

Super User:

[image]

Other sites:

[image]

So it seems like Super User still has the same top bar as there was on other sites when the new top bar was first implemented. Is there any reason for this?

Comment: .... I don't think I have actually ever noticed...

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I Never noticed either, but I'm using [script - Top-navigation choices - Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/questions/7603/top-navigation-choices) :)

Comment: Haven't you heard that size doesn't matter?  :-)

Comment: Nooooooooooooo don't make them change it!!!!!

Comment: Changing it would *definitely* help when we are using the desktop version of the Super User site on our mobile devices.

Comment: [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com) has a smaller top bar as well.

Comment: ... as does [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/).